# Are carrier-specific questions appropriate in AE?

Tags: discussion, scope

How should we divide the line between questions that are more about specific carriers rather than Android?

An example question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/prepaid-cards-for-the-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm inclined to think they're off-topic.  It's one thing if it's a carrier-specific question that is also Android-specific (an example fails me at the moment), but the example you mention has nothing to do with Android; the user just happens to have an Android phone.

Comment: Agree, they come under the "Too Localized" condition pretty much by definition. Even worse the questioner there is not even interested in the whole country, just Vermont, and the whole question of area codes is totally irrelevant to many countries where mobile phones have their own codes and aren't tied down to geographic area codes.