# Carrier tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

We have tags for individual wireless carriers. Some carriers have exclusive devices for their network, and virtually all of them customize Android to add their own software. (Euphemistically known as "bloatware".)

However, it's very rare for a question to be appropriately tagged with a carrier. Almost all of the time the asker is tagging their question to describe their device, not their question.

Further:

- There may not be a tag for the asker's specific, carrier-branded device
- At least one tag is required, so the asker had to add *something*
- etc.

You can help by looking through the questions with these carrier tags and

- removing the tag if the question is not about the carrier in general; remember, [carrier-specific questions are off-topic here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/are-carrier-specific-questions-appropriate-in-ae)

  - this is probably also an indication that the question has other tags to describe the device and not the question
- confirming that it really belongs

Here are the tags with their current question counts

- [verizon](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verizon) × 41
- [att](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/att) × 17
- [sprint](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprint) × 15
- [t-mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-mobile) × 14
- [orange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange) × 3
- [virgin-mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virgin-mobile) × 2

---

See also:

- [Manufacturer tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/manufacturer-tag-cleanup)

Comment: virgin-mobile has been cleaned.